# Three Cards Monte game

Tags: java, homework

I have written the following code for the Three Cards Monte game. It works as expected and returns the required output.

However when I tried to turn it in to the teacher, he keeps saying its too long.

Is there any way to shorten it but make sure it returns the same output?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ThreeCardsMonte {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int ace; 
        int guess;

        ace = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*3);

        System.out.println("You slide up to Fast Eddie's card table and plop down your cash.");
        System.out.println("He glances at you out of the corner of his eye and starts shuffling.");
        System.out.println("He lays down three cards.");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Which one is the ace?");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("##  ##  ##");
        System.out.println("##  ##  ##");
        System.out.println("1   2   3");
        guess = keyboard.nextInt();

        if ((ace == 1) && (guess == 1)) { 
            System.out.println("You nailed it! Fast Eddie reluctantly hands over your winnings, scowling.");
            System.out.println("AA  ##  ##");
            System.out.println("AA  ##  ##");
            System.out.println("1   2   3");
  }
        else if ((ace == 1) && (guess != 1)) {
            System.out.println("Ha! Fast Eddie wins again! The ace was card number " +ace+".");
            System.out.println("AA  ##  ##");
            System.out.println("AA  ##  ##");
            System.out.println("1   2   3");
  }
        else if ((ace == 2) && (guess == 2)) { 
            System.out.println("You nailed it! Fast Eddie reluctantly hands over your winnings, scowling.");
            System.out.println("##  AA  ##");
            System.out.println("##  AA  ##");
            System.out.println("1   2   3");
  }
        else if ((ace == 2) && (guess != 2)) {
            System.out.println("Ha! Fast Eddie wins again! The ace was card number " +ace+".");
            System.out.println("##  AA  ##");
            System.out.println("##  AA  ##");
            System.out.println("1   2   3");
  }
        else if ((ace == 3) && (guess == 3)) {
            System.out.println("You nailed it! Fast Eddie reluctantly hands over your winnings, scowling.");
            System.out.println("##  ##  AA");
            System.out.println("##  ##  AA");
            System.out.println("1   2   3");  
  }
        else if ((ace == 3) && (guess != 3)) {
            System.out.println("Ha! Fast Eddie wins again! The ace was card number " +ace+".");
            System.out.println("##  ##  AA");
            System.out.println("##  ##  AA");
            System.out.println("1   2   3");  
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want it to be shorter? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: I guess that's what she said eh? Jokes apart, what do you think you can do make *it* shorter.

Comment: Honestly I have no idea what to do here. I just don't know where to start

Comment: why not eliminate all of that just do a simple `if (ace == guess)` and have an `else` case as well

Comment: Well... You could start by looking at your else statements. There are really only two possibilities. `ace == guess` and `ace != guess`. This can be simplified to `if(ace == guess){//dostuff}else{do other stuff};`

Comment: @Ishnark I need to make sure that the ace card is flipped over at the end of the users guess

Comment: You can create a method to print all that four lines ("sharps, 1, 2, 3 and the message as a parameter") that alone will shorten your program a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of repeats

```
 if (ace == guess) { 
      System.out.println("You nailed it! Fast Eddie reluctantly hands over your winnings, scowling.");
  }
  else  {
      System.out.println("Ha! Fast Eddie wins again! The ace was card number " +ace+".");
  }

  if (ace == 1) {
      System.out.println("AA  ##  ##");
      System.out.println("AA  ##  ##");
  }
  else if (ace == 2) {
      System.out.println("##  AA  ##");
      System.out.println("##  AA  ##");
  }
  else if (ace == 3) {
      System.out.println("##  ##  AA");
      System.out.println("##  ##  AA");
  }
  System.out.println("1   2   3");
```

Could put the ace position in an array and just reference it by index
I don't know java to write an array

Answer (score 1):

Using an array would help a lot here.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ThreeCardsMonte {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        final String[] aces = {
            "##  ##  ##",
            "AA  ##  ##",
            "##  AA  ##",
            "##  ##  AA"
        };
        final String nums = "1   2   3";

        System.out.println("You slide up to Fast Eddie's card table and plop down your cash.");
        System.out.println("He glances at you System.out of the corner of his eye and starts shuffling.");
        System.out.println("He lays down three cards.");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Which one is the ace?");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println(aces[0]);
        System.out.println(aces[0]);
        System.out.println(nums);

        final int ace = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 3);
        final Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int guess = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println(
            (ace == guess) ?
                "You nailed it! Fast Eddie reluctantly hands over your winnings, scowling." :
                "Ha! Fast Eddie wins again! The ace was card number " + ace + ".");

        System.out.println(aces[ace]);
        System.out.println(aces[ace]);
        System.out.println(nums);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each last three print in each if are the same for equals ace, so what you can do is

```
if(ace == x) {
    if(guess == x)
       System.out.println("You nailed it! Fast Eddie reluctantly hands over your winnings, scowling.");
    else
       System.out.println("Ha! Fast Eddie wins again! The ace was card number " +ace+".");
    System.out.println("##  ##  AA");
    System.out.println("##  ##  AA");
    System.out.println("1   2   3"); 
}
```

Comment: Don't encourage learners to omit braces.

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten the amount of if statements from 6 to 4:

```
if (ace == guess) {
    if (ace == 1) {
        Code for if ace was one;
    }
    if (ace ==2) {
        Code for if ace was two;
    }
    if (ace == 3) {
        Code for if ace was three;
    }
else {
    Whatever code;
}
```

You can also probably use a switch which would be less characters but around the same amount of lines.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Abdenaceur Lichiheb's answer, use the special character \n to make multiple lines if you want to avoid multiple `println`s.

```
System.out.println("##  ##  AA\n##  ##  AA\n1   2   3");
```